# Conectar Base de Datos MySQL con Python

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, base-de-datos

solicitando de su apoyo para encontrar la razón por la cuál mi código de Python no se conecta a un Server diferente de Localhost montado en XAMPP. El error que lanza es sobre mi dirección IP, no tanto sobre la del servidor. Anexo código y salida del error. ¡Saludos!

```
"""
Conexión a base de datos MySQL
"""
import MySQLdb
from os import listdir

#Definimos valores para la conexión
db_Host = '1XX.XXX.XX.227'
db_User = 'root'
db_Pass = ''
db_Name = 'desbordes'

#Función de conexión
datos = [db_Host, db_User, db_Pass, db_Name]

#creamos la conexión
conn = MySQLdb.connect(*datos)
cursor = conn.cursor()

with open('C:/ruta/archivo.txt', mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as entrada:

    conteo_bc1 = 0

    #Ciclo que lee cada linea en el archivo Bcom
    for linea in entrada:
        if "CASH" in linea:
            conteo_bc1 += 1

    query = 'INSERT INTO Bcom (fecha, menu, total_desbordes) VALUES ("{}","{}","{}")'.format(fecha,"CASH",conteo_bc1)

    cursor.execute(query)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Al realizar la ejecución del script, obtengo la siguiente salida:

```
.OperationalError: (1130, "Host 'mi_IP' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server")
```

Comment: Que no tendrias que apuntar a la direccion del servidor?  Que sistema operativo usas?

Comment: Hola alanfcm, así es, en el código la dirección del host es la del servidor al que quiero llegar, pero el error muestra mi IP, utilizo Windows 7.

Comment: El servidor de BD remoto al que apuntas, está habilitado para recibir conexiones remotas? Revisaste los permisos y accesos del lado del servidor?

Answer (score 0):

intenta escribirlo todo en la misma linea con comilla doble:

```
conn=MySQLdb.connect("1XX.XXX.XX.227","root","","desbordes)
```

Espero te funcione!